# How can I run old part of a website on a sub domain at PHP 4

Tags: php, .htaccess

My global PHP is set at PHP 5 for a wordpress website. One page directs to the sub domain.

I have inherited an old part of a website that needs to be at PHP 4 running on the sub domain. ( Which will be re-built later in the year ).

How can I set the PHP version of the sub domain to PHP 4?

I have tried

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 4
AddHandler php-stable .php
```

but this caused the browser to display code!!

Hope someone can help! - Thanks

Comment: How is anyone supposed to answer this question? What webserver are you running? What OS are you running? How much control do you have over the environment? Give us a clue here.

Comment: Hi Trig - I do apologies the site is hosted on 1 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good guide on how to setup PHP5 and PHP4 on the same server: http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2_with_php5_and_php4

Comment: and TRiG

I managed to solve this issue. For 1 and 1 I added the below entry to .htaccess at the root of the subdomain 

    AddHandler x-mapp-php4 .php

Your link Moov Tony helped a lot thanks